# Перевод дробной части числа в восьмиричную СС Паскаль

Tags: pascal, числа, системы-счисления

Есть задание:
В числовую переменную вводится отличное от нуля вещественное десятичное число. Необходимо вывести на экран представление этого числа в восьмеричной системе счисления. Перевод дробной части числа ограничить семью знаками. Предусмотреть проверку правильности ввода информации.
Написал код для этой задачи, но без вещественных чисел. Т.е. тип данных integer.

```
var x, nmb, z: integer;
begin
readln(x);
nmb:=0;
z:=1;
while x <> 0 do begin
nmb:= nmb + z * (x mod 8);
x:= x div 8;
z := z * 10;
end;
writeln(nmb);
end.
```

Непонятно, как работать с вещественными числами, переводить дробную часть в восьмеричную СС и ограничить результат восьмью знаками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот есть [правило и схемы перевода](http://book.kbsu.ru/theory/chapter4/1_4_7.html) десятичных дробей в другую систему счисления.

Вот функция:

```
function DecimalTo8Str (Precision : integer; value : double) : String;
var
  Val : Extended;
  IntVal : Int64;
  FracVal : double;
  StrInt : String;
  StrFrac : String;
  i : Integer;
begin
  // Получаем целую и дробную части числа.
  IntVal := Trunc(value);
  FracVal := Frac(value);

  //Переводим целую часть.
  StrInt := '';
  repeat
    StrInt := IntToStr(IntVal mod 8) + StrInt;
    IntVal := IntVal div 8;
  until IntVal = 0;

  // Если дробная часть = 0, то перевод закончен.
  if FracVal = 0 then begin
    Result := StrInt;
    exit;
  end;

  //Переводим дробную часть. Точность - до Precision цифр после запятой.
  StrFrac := '';
  for i := 1 to Precision do begin
    Val := FracVal * 8;
    StrFrac := StrFrac + IntToStr(Trunc(Val));
    FracVal := Frac(Val);
    //Если дробная часть = 0, то перевод закончен.
    if FracVal = 0 then Break;
  end;
  Result := StrInt + ',' + StrFrac;
end
```

;